# Chamfer Distance between two images in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

given two images I want to find chamfer distance between them.
I have converted them into edge image using canny edge but I don't know where to go from here.
The distance is being calculated for nearest neighbor classification. I know L2 or some other would work but I am interested chamfer distance.

Comment: Compute distance transform of one image, then sum these distance values for the edge pixels in the other image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's brilliant!